# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_bokeh' BUT... My python enviroment has it installed. I even did pip install jupyter_bokeh

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh, panel, interactive, ipywidgets

I am at my wits end. I'm trying to render a panel interact widget with some Python code, and it keeps giving me an error that bokeh doesn't exist.

The issue originally was that my panel interact widgets weren't being interactive. It would display a graph, but the widget wouldn't change the visual. I was making a moving slider object but as I used the slider data wouldn't change.

Someone told me to run this command in anaconda to fix it. So my widgets will be interactive.

`conda install nb_conda_kernelsconda install python_en`

So now when I run the Python cell in my notebook I get the no module bokeh error.

So I do an install of bokeh

`pip install jupyter_bokeh`

And I verify in my environment that bokeh exists.

`conda list bokeh`

[bokeh exists in environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4z9o.png)

When that didn't work, I simply created a fresh new python environment and that also is giving me the same issue. bokeh exists but it errors saying it doesn't.

Comment: If you are getting an error that the module `jupyter_bokeh` does not exist, than that means you have an environment mix-up of some sort. 100% you have installed `jupyter_bokeh` into a different python environment than the one you are running jupyter notebook out of.

Comment: Agreed. Also, you'll probably have fewer troubles if you stick with _either_ pip _or_ conda rather than mixing the two.  If you do use pip, using `python -m pip` instead of just `pip` can avoid some of these issues.

Comment: I am using the correct environment. I have run install after install of jupyter_bokeh, checked that it did install, and it's still giving me the ModuleError. The only solution for me is to completely delete my entire anaconda and re-install everything to get rid of whatever this issue is.

Comment: Welp, I had no choice but to completely uninstall anaconda completely and then re-install, and then rebuild every python environment from the ground up. And now the issue doesn't exist anymore. That will be my go-to  solution for every problem from now on. I bet if I had a problem with my monitor not displaying anything you all would conclude that I didn't turn on the monitor to begin with. Thanks for the shitty help.